# Linux+C : fork() and waitpid() acting funny

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I'm taking an OS undergrad course, and I'm unable to correctly do a lab practical question that came last year in exams. Here's how it goes:
PART 1:

1. scanf takes an integer n, and then a loop runs as `for(i=1 to n) { fork(); }`
2. the program must print `pid()` and `ppid()` from each process and also output to a file as a csv (I'm not concerned about csv part yet because I'm not getting correct result in command line yet).
3. For example, an output for n=2: 
   **pid= 8450,ppid=8000 

   pid= 8452,ppid= 8450 

   pid= 8453,ppid= 8450 

   pid= 8455,ppid= 8452**   which I can get more or less with n=2, but I think my ids lose order when the input is larger (like n = 4). I have to run the code for n=4 and n=5 and note the readings to complete this part.

PART2: Finally I need to modify the code making sure the parent waits for the child to die
soon after the fork and then breaks from the loop and exits. Pseudocode is given as:

```
    for (i= 1 to n) {
    fork()
    ………
    if parent:
      waitpid(pid)
      break
    }
```

My sluggish code that I came up with is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int pid, pid2;
    int pPID, pPID2;
    FILE *fptr;
    
    fptr = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
    
    pid = getpid();
    pPID = getppid();
    
    printf("pid (parent): %d\t ppid: %d\n", pid, pPID);
    
    printf("enter n \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        fflush(stdin);
        fork();
    }
    
    pid2 = getpid();
    pPID2 = getppid();
    printf("pid2 (child): %d\t ppid2: %d\n", pid2, pPID2);
    fprintf(fptr, "pid2 (child): %d\t ppid2: %d\n", pid2, pPID2);
    fclose(fptr);
    
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
 }
```

I have the following questions:

1. While I get a correct output when n=2, when I enter n >= 3, some of the results are not really in a proper sequence. Like a parent finishing before a child and the result  not really looking like it's in the right sequence. How do I refactor the code to tackle this and is this something I should even bother at all? I entered n = 3, and this is what I got: 
   **pid (Parent): 9610     ppid: 2098 

   pid2 (Child): 9611   ppid2: 9610 

   pid2 (Child): 9615   ppid2: 9611 

   pid2 (Child): 9614   ppid2: 9610 

   pid2 (Child): 9613   ppid2: 9611 

   pid2 (Child): 9612   ppid2: 9610 

   pid2 (Child): 9617   ppid2: 9612 

   pid2 (Child): 9616   ppid2: 9613**
   Do you think this sequence is correct?

2. I don't really understand the PART2. What does `if parent` even mean in the pseudocode? It is the pPID (of the original parent) or pPID2 (of each forked process's ppid)? And what does the `'pid'` in `waitpid(pid)` mean? I'm completely clueless about what exactly to do in the for-loop, and feel completely dumb while taking this course.
3. Any general/alternate ways to approach the question? I printf the parent's id before the for-loop to make sure it's always at the top. Should this be the case? How can I make sure this happens without explicitly not printing it as a separate printf so as to not lose order?

Comment: It's up to the operating system to schedule processes and the order in which they run. It will most certainly not be sequentially.

Comment: Once you have several processes, they may run in parallel or in any order; it is entirely possible that a parent may finish before a child.  Whether you need to account for that is something you have to check in the requirements of the assignment.  If you do, then you need some sort of synchronization, such as semaphores, and the assignment becomes quite a bit more complex.

Comment: "if parent" probably means "if this process is the parent", i.e. if the preceding fork call returned nonzero.  `pid` probably means the PID of the child, i.e. the nonzero value returned by that fork call.

Comment: By the way, the C specification explicitly mention that calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like e.g. `stdin`) is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, thanks for the tip about fflush . What do you think about Part 2, how do I use waitpid(pid) inside the for-loop to make sure the parent process waits for child to die after calling fork()? The pseudocode provided in the assignment is very python-like and I can't really understand that one. Thanks!

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, that helped. I have a follow up, How would the result be different from the one from Part1 in that case? The pseudocode provided is really bad for someone who never used python.

Comment: From the assignment it seems you should print the pids *inside* the loop, and then if in the parent (when `fork` returns a value different from `0`) then you call `waitpid` with the value that `fork` returned.